# impossible to do anything with my usb stick

Tags: usb, disk-formatting

So a few months ago, I used a USB stick with windows to run wii games with The Homebrew channel. Everything was fine until i noticed that my usb key wouldn't add files on it anymore, even though there was still some space on it. So I tried deleting files, and it appeared like they were deleted, but when I plug my USB Key back into my pc the files are here again. And I can't do anything about it : I tried formating (didn't work), deleting every files (didn't work), changing permissions of the usb stick to write (won't let me change the permissions).
I thought it was my pc but I tried on MacOS, Windows and now I'm on Ubuntu, and it still doesn't work. Does anybody know how to solve this problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Possibly it is broken. Destroy it physically and buy a new one (preferably a good brand).

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: Your issue isn't related to the OS, but is a hardware issue as I see it, with *flash* media being a consumable that will indeed fail (*but modern USB sticks hold far more than floppy drives, tape drives etc. they replaced*).  You've confirmed it isn't usable in three OSes, thus it reads like you're asking about a hardware device failure, replace it (*some devices have SMART & other diagnostics built in, consumable flash media doesn't as it'd increase cost more than device is worth so its normally replaced*)